# Value Of Pointers

Tags: c++

In my book, it says Pointers are addresses and have a numerical value. You can print out the value of a pointer as cout << (unsigned long)(p)
Write code to compare p,p+1,q, and q+1. Explain the results, Im not sure what the book wants me to so here's what I have. Does anyone Know if I am doing this right

```
int num = 20;
double dbl = 20.0;
int *p = &num;
double *q = &dbl;
cout << (unsigned long)(q) << endl;
q = q + 1;
cout << (unsigned long)(q) << endl;

cout << (unsigned long)(p) << endl;
p = p + 1 ;
cout << (unsigned long)(p) << endl;
```

Comment: While in most implementations the size of `unsigned long` and a pointer is the same, your book is wrong if it claims that you can always use a cast to `unsigned long` to print a pointer. The correct way to print a pointer is to cast it to `void*`.

Comment: What are your doubts actually in doing that right?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is the `void*` cast even necessary?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it helps a great deal when the pointer is a `char*` ;)

Comment: @Quentin That's true, but wasn't in question.

Comment: I'd suspect the OP is confused about pointer arithmetics most probably, but doesn't tell us.

Comment: The thing about pointer is, they hold an address and almost know the type of the memory they point to.
When you increase a pointer by 1, the compiler increases the address by the size of the type and not by 1.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It makes sure the correct overload is used. Besides the standard overloads for `char*` and `basic_streambuf<...>*`, who know what other user-defined overloads there might be.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg _"who know what other user-defined overloads there might be."_ Fair point.

Comment: My output shows that the value of int pointers are larger than double pointers why is that??     int pointer val: 7338932   double pointer val: 7338916

Comment: @Marco Without knowing the *full* output it's hard to see what you mean. Where the compiler places the variable `num` and `dbl` is really irrelevant.

Comment: @Marco pointers are addresses.  Similar to street addresses.  Your int lives at address 7338932.  Your double lives close by at 7338916.  Pointers/addresses are not values - which is why when you "move one address" (pointer arithmatic) the "value" changes by more than 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's the pointer arithmetic you have problems with, let my try to to show how it's done in a more "graphical" way:

Lets say we have a pointer variable `ptr` which points to an array of integers, something like

```
int array[4] = { 1234, 5678, 9012, 3456 };
int* ptr = array;  // Makes `ptr` point to the first element of `array`
```

In memory it looks something like

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 1234 | 5678 | 9012 | 3456 |
+------+------+------+------+
^      ^      ^      ^
|      |      |      |
ptr    ptr+1  ptr+2  ptr+3
```

<sub>The first is technically `ptr+0`</sub>

When adding one to a pointer, you go to the next element in the "array".

Perhaps now you start to see some similarities between pointer arithmetic and array indexing. And that is because there *is* a common thread here: For any pointer *or array* `p` and valid index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly the same as `*(p + i)`.

Using the knowledge that `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)` makes it easier to understand how an array can be used as a pointer to its first element. We start with a pointer to the first element of `array` (as defined above): `&array[0]`. This is equal to the expression `&*(array + 0)`. The address-of (`&`) and dereference (`*`) operators cancel out each, leaving us with `(array + 0)`. Adding zero to anything can be removed as well, so now we have `(array)`. And finally we can remove the parentheses, leaving us with `array`. That means that `&array[0]` is equal to `array`.

Comment: You can even write i[p], which will be translated to *(i + p), which yields the same object, or even -1[p+size], to get the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You do it right, if you want to print the decimal representation of the addresses your pointers point to.
If you wonder, why the results are such, you need to learn **pointer arithmetic.** If you add `1` to any pointer, it's address will be increased by `sizeof(<type>)`, where `type` is *the type of the variable your pointer points to*.
So that, if you have a pointer to `int` and increment it, the address will be increased by `sizeof(int)`, which is, most likely, four.